# Remove leading zeros from %m and %d in MySQL date_format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, date-formatting

The following query produces a date that looks like this `2016, 01, 02`. How do I get it to remove trailing zeros from the month and day so that it looks like this `2016, 1, 2`?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%Y, %m, %d') AS day, SUM(earning_amount) AS amount
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_account_id = ?
GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)
ORDER BY earning_created
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `%c` to format the month without the leading zero and `%e` to format the day of the month:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%Y, %c, %e') AS day, -- Here! 
         SUM(earning_amount) AS amount
FROM     earnings
WHERE    earning_account_id = ?
GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)
ORDER BY earning_created
```